# Как узнать какие пользователи подключены к Flask-Socket

Tags: python, flask

Суть проблемы. Мне нужно показывать кто сейчас онлайн на сайте. Думал каждую секунду отправлять socket.on('online'), а на сервере проверять кто сейчас онлайн. Так вот вопрос как проверить кто сейчас онлайн? Реализация проекта на Flask с Flask-SocketIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря как вы идентифицируете пользователей. Примитивный пример с идентификацией по IP-адресу:

```
connected_users = set()

@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    connected_users.add(request.remote_addr)

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    connected_users.remove(request.remote_addr)

@socketio.on_error()
def error_handler(e):
    connected_users.remove(request.remote_addr)
```

Comment: Спасибо.   Мне нужно удалять пользователя со списка когда он покинул сайт.  Это error handler?

Comment: При отключении вызывается `on_disconnect`, а `error_handler` при какой-либо ошибке, например, обрыве связи.